# Distributed File System Replication

Tags: replication, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-distributed-file-system

We have large source of data that currently is being replicated on multiple servers through our own services. Data size is around 10TB and has millions of folders/files. Data size increases daily by 10-20GB. OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

We are looking for more automated and robust files replication system. DFS Replication from Microsoft is an option but someone pointed out that it might not work on such a large data. Does anyone has an experience with it and can confirm this limitation? If that's the case is there any other free system out there?

Thanks